# JQUERY Ajax call is not firing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have created my Ajax call as it can be seen below, but somehow it is not firing.  When I request the data to be sent via POST method, it still shows on the
 URL:xxxxxx/index.php?username=martin&password=1234".  No errors displayed on the console too.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title> RBH-PAS system </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "pascss/index.css " >
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //event.preventDefault();

    $("#submit").click(function(){

        var x = $('#username').value();
        var y = $('#password').value();

        console.log(x);

            if(x==null || x ==""){
                alert("Username must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
                else if(y==null || y ==""){
                alert("Password must be filled out");
                return false;
                }


        else{

        $.ajax({
                    url: "login.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {username:x, password:y},
                    cache: false,
                        success: function(result){
                        //if(result == 0 || result == null ){
                        //alert("result");
                        //}
                        }
                });
        }
        return false;

    });
});

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1><CENTER> WELCOME TO PAS DASHBOARD</CENTER></h1>

    <div id="login">

        <h2><span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>Sign In</h2>


        <form id ="login1">
            <fieldset>

                <p><label for="username">Username</p>
                <p><input type="text" id ="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required></p>

                <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
                <p><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required></p>

                <p><input type="submit" id =" submit" value="Sign In" ></p>

            </fieldset> 

</body>
```

Comment: `x` and `y` can never be null,unless the selector doesn't exist so you don't need to check if they are null, instead only check if they are an empty string. if the selector doesn't exist, your code will throw an exception.

Comment: Where is the FORM closing tag? Have you check your network tab in console? And what about `id =" submit"` with the non valid former space?

Comment: @r3wt I have just tried that as well and is still behaves the same

Comment: `url: "login.php",` are posting to correct url.

Comment: At least try: `<input type="submit" id ="submit" value="Sign In">` See ID attribute

Comment: `id =" submit"` a space in the id attribute.

Comment: @Nurettin it was a side note, had nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: it may be because you're not cancelling the sending of the form. so in effect you are sending it normally and sending it via ajax and as you have no method attr on the form and the default is get then it's showing in the url. add a form method=post, or preventDefault in jquery

Comment: @Billy he has it in the code, but its inside of document ready, instead of being inside the click function.

Comment: @r3wt No, it is inside click handler. It looks like it was just an issue regarding ID of submit button. This question should be closed . BTW, OP doesn't give any news

Comment: I know, but as default sending isn't being cancelled, it's sending via get aswell as via ajax. add  e.preventDefault(); inside ajax call

Comment: there is alot wrong with this code though. 99% of the time there is no reason to use `$.ajax()` for XHR, with the 1% of the time being an ajax file upload, which really you don't even need now with HTML 5 file api, because you can read the binary file data to base64 with the html5 file api and then submit it via a normal post request. We're really not helping people much if we just fix their deprecated code. that's why my answer shows the modern way to process data from a form for usage with an ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a button not a submitbutton for click events so change your submit button to:

```
<input type="button" id ="loginbutton" value="Sign In" />
```

and change that line

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#loginbutton").click(function(){
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution. it encourages backward programming. my solution posted above shows the best way to work with form elements to obtain their values, iterate over them and check to make sure they are there, then serialize the values and submit the form.

Comment: I think my solution to fix the problem the OP has is quick and clean.

Comment: i'm not saying your solution doesn't work. it does, because it prevents the form from being submitted. i would rather give people a valuable new trick than show them a work around that encourages bad programming.

Comment: many thanks to everyone trying to help, it is working now. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on the url: xxxxxx/index.php?username=martin&password=1234, try the GET method in AJAX. Or receive the variables inside the login.php page with $_POST

Answer (score 0):

A fix for your code.

first, you want to use a normal form:

```
<form id="form-id">

    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="text" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

and some new javascript. first we'll bind to the submit event on the form, then prevent the default action. then, we'll use serialize() to serialize the inputs. next we iterate over these inputs with `$.each()` to make sure they are populated with data. finally, we submit the post request with `$.post()`. we then return false.

```
$(function(){

//The better way(IMO)


    //bind to the form submit function.
    $('#form-id').submit(function(event){
        event.PreventDefault();//prevent the default submit mechanism
        var error = false;
        var QueryString = $(this).serialize(); //serialize the form inputs into a k:v format for a http request.

        //make sure our fields are populated with data
        $.each(QueryString,function(key, value){
            if(value == ""){
                alert(key+" can't be empty");
                error = true;
            }
        });

        if(error === false){
            $.post('login.php',QueryString, function(data){
                //do something with result
            }).success(function(){
                //success callback fires immediately, but doesn't have access to the ajax callback data.
            }).error(function(){
                //do something on error.
            })
        }
        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: 1 more thing to add, you could take  it a step further by sanitizing data in the `$.each()` loop, but you should probably handle that server side anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#submit").click(function(){

                    var x = $('#username').val();
                    var y = $('#password').val();

                    console.log(x);

                        if(x==null || x ==""){
                            alert("Username must be filled out");
                            return false;
                        }
                            else if(y==null || y ==""){
                            alert("Password must be filled out");
                            return false;
                            }


                    else{

                    $.ajax({
                                url: "login.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {username:x, password:y},
                                cache: false,
                                    success: function(result){
                                    //if(result == 0 || result == null ){
                                    //alert("result");
                                    //}
                                    }
                            });
                    }
                    return false;

                });
            });

        </script>


<form id ="login1">
            <fieldset>

                <p><label for="username">Username</p>
                <p><input type="text" id ="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" required></p>

                <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
                <p><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required></p>

                <p><input type="submit" id ="submit" value="Sign In" ></p>

            </fieldset> 
     </form>
```